# How to set maximum width of file tabs (i.e., tabset_control) in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

In Sublime Text 2, the file tabs (`tabset_control` class) would shrink in width if many tabs were open. This made it easy to see many tabs at once.

In Sublime Text 3, this behavior seems to have changed. File tabs occupy the full width of the filename even if many tabs are open.

Based on the Sublime docs, there doesn't appear to be a way to enforce a maximum width on file tabs: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/themes.html

Is there a way to enforce a max width of file tabs when there's not enough space to show all tabs at normal width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't set a maximum width, but it does revert to the Sublime Text 2 behavior of shrinking file tabs so all are visible.

In `Sublime Text > Preferences > Settings - User`, add this setting:

```
"enable_tab_scrolling": false
```